# How can I limit this term to a 3 piece hit?

Tags: regex, perl

It would be the real task to `sadfsadf! Ghfgh% fgh65 %%` of this text to replace the first 3 characters that are true for regexp, so replace it with 'o' `sadfsadfoghfghofgh65o%`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

@list=<>;
chomp(@list);

foreach(@list) {
    if($_ =~ m/\W/) {
        # here is the problem because all the characters you find it 
        #  overwrite it, but I only need to translate 3 characters from it
        $_ =~ s/\W/o/g;
        print $_."\n";
    }
    else {
        print "->\n";
    }
}

#start string => sadfsadf!ghfgh%fgh65%%
#result my program => sadfsadfoghfghofgh65oo
#and I need it => sadfsadfoghfghofgh65o%
```

change only the first 3 results to 'o'

Comment: http://www.kepfeltoltes.eu/images/2019/03/240problem.jpg

Comment: You have tagged with Perl. Are you using this in a Perl program, or somewhere else where you have the PCRE regex engine? It is very easy to solve this with the code that runs the regex.

Comment: This is a little unclear to me. In the first example, `"sadfsadf!ghfgh%fgh65%%"` do you not want the `"%%"` because it's two `"%"`? I.e. if it was `"sadfsadf!ghfgh%fgh65%abc%"` you'd expect `"!"`, `"%"`, `"%"` **and another** `"%"`? Or do you just want the first three characters of all matches? I.e for `"sadfsadf!!ghfgh%fgh65%%"` get `"!"`, `"!"` and `"%"`?

Comment: Does it have to be 3 or just not the last one?

Comment: Suddenly, it is a different question??

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to go:

```
use feature 'say';

my $in = 'sadfsadf!ghfgh%fgh65%%';
$in =~ s/\W/o/ for 1..3;
say $in;
```

**Output:**

```
sadfsadfoghfghofgh65o%
```

Comment: @zsolt2255: Fine, but mine seems simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem
Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
while ($be=<STDIN>)
{
chomp $be;
push (@list, $be);
}

foreach $a (@list)
{
$count=0;
    if ($a=~/\W/)
    {
    while (($a=~m/\W/g) && ($count < 3))
    {
    $count++;
    $a=~s/\W/o/;
    }
    print "$a\n";
    }
    else {print "->\n";}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your data in 'list' file

```
 perl -pe 'for $i(1..3){s/\W/o/} ' list
```

on bash if you put data such `list='sadfsadf!ghfgh%fgh65%%'`

```
for((i=1;i<=3;i++)){ list=`echo $list|sed -E "s/\W/Y/"`; }
```